Keystonejs 6 validating session token
We are currently building an app with Keystone 6 as backend and have a security concern when it comes to authenticating users. With the built in authentication method, I can use someone's token to get full access to a user's account, by simply modifying the token cookie which is then used in the request headers. We are wondering how we could secure the process. Some sort of middleware like redis possibly that would validate the legitimacy of the request using a fingerprint stored against the token during the initial authentication request. Any advise would be really appreciated.
